# Write files in R that supports Unix EOL (LF)

Tags: r, file

I am using `R` programming in windows to create some files using `writeLines()`. But I need to use those files in Linux. So how can I make EOL character as LF instead of CRLF? My code snippet look like this.

```
writeLines(c("line1","line2"), file_con, sep = "\n")
```

I tried by setting sep as `"\r"` but didn't help.

Comment: How are you getting them to your linux machine? Many FTP programs will translate line endings for you. You really don't want to make a file on Windows that isn't coded properly for windows.

Comment: Actually i am using WinSCP to upload files from windows to Linux. There is an option in notepad++ for EOL conversion. So i also need to do something like that in my R script.

Comment: Open the output file in binary mode and set eol="\n"

Comment: Just set the WinSCP transfer mode to "text"

Comment: if using `write.table()` instead of `writeLines()` is an option, you can use the `eol` argument of `write.table()`

Comment: Just set the WinSCP transfer mode to "text", this way worked for me! thanks.